# When translating an entire passage, some sentences may be missed.(Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-zh-en)

Tags: python, transform

When translating an entire passage, some sentences may be missed.If a passage is divided into multiple short sentences for translation, the translation results will be correct.

```
tokenizer_zh = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model_zh = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
parm = translation_zh_to_en
translation = pipline(parm,model_zh,tokenizer_zh)
result = translation(text[:510])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICOyb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p47Iu.png)
How to solve this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.